# How can I remove crashlytics from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, twitter, crashlytics

I need to remove crashlytics from my iOS app, as am using STTwitter API to get user's Twitter credentials from the phone. This used to work fine on my device, but now I can't get the credentials for some reason, after some digging I found that I can still get the credentials on the simulator and since crashlytics doesn't work with the simulator am sensing the problem is with it, specially that there's this badge on Fabric mac app which indicates that crashlytics needs to be updated but even after I update it still I can not get the credentials and this "update badge" is back on after a while.

Comment: Do the opposite of what you needed to install it. Remove relevant code, remove the framework (and anything else needed).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I can't say that removing crashlytics will solve your problem, but here's how you would do it:

1) Look in your `AppDelegate` file.  Look in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.  Remove the line `Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey("abc123")`

2) Goto your build phases in Xcode for your target.  Find the shell script that looks like `./Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/run somelongstringhere` and remove it

3) Find the crashlytics framework in your navigation panel of Xcode right click and either remove the reference or delete it all together.  If you installed via cocoa pods then remove it from your podfile.

4) Delete the crashlytics app from your system if you so desire by looking in your applications folder.