# Mach-O Linker Error integrating Crashlytics with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, run-script

Added Crashlytics/Fabric SDK into my projects *manually* several months ago, now I'm trying to work with it via CocoaPods.

I first removed Crashlytics/Fabric from my project following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314277/how-can-i-remove-crashlytics-from-my-ios-app) then added it back from CocoaPods following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071277/integrate-fabric-crashlytics-via-cocoapods).

Call it with simple `[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and build my project, bang!

[image]

Here's my run script in Target > Build Phases:

[image]

And the navigation panel looks like:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**

I did add `security.framework, libz, libc++, and SystemConfiguration.framework`in my project... still not working.

Comment: Could this help you?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152442/what-is-causing-this-crashlytics-compile-warning-auto-linking-supplied-f

Comment: @GenieWanted hmm I cannot link any framework since I add it via CocoaPods... but thanks!

Comment: Did you find a fix? Having same problem